# Excel: Macro to list all the values in list conditionally in a cell

Tags: excel, macros

I am trying to write a Macro where i need to list all the resources which belong to specific project with their roles.
For example:

```
Resource    Project 1   Project 2   Project 3
X1          Manager     Team Lead   
X2          Analyst                 Team Lead
X3                      Consultant  
X4          BA                      Consultant
```

Then result should be:

```
            List
Project 1   X1, X2 and X4
Project 2   X1 and X3
Project 3   X2 and X4
```

Please suggest as how should i achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this UDF.

**[Module1 (Code)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/List%20all%20the%20values%20in%20list%20conditionally%20in%20a%20cell.xlsb)**

```
Option Explicit

Function listProjectResources(rng As Range, rsc As Range)
    Dim tmp As String, r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    Set rsc = rsc.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If Not IsEmpty(rng.Cells(r, c)) Then
                tmp = tmp & _
                      IIf(CBool(Len(tmp)), " and ", vbNullString) & _
                      rsc.Cells(r, c).Value2
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    If n > 2 Then _
        tmp = Replace(tmp, " and ", Chr(44) & Chr(32), 1, n - 2)

    listProjectResources = tmp
End Function
```

Use in G4 as,

```
=listProjectResources(INDEX($B$2:$D$5, 0, MATCH(F4, B$1:D$1, 0)), A$2:A$5)
```

[image: Concat_Project_Resources]